# What are the keys for statusOfValueForKey

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation

Can anyone find the key list for `AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading:statusOfValueForKey`?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading_Protocol/index.html

From some examples,
I can see "tracks", and "duration".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Key list contain basically all the properties of `AVAsset`. Like duration, tracks, metadata, playable, exportable etc. List is long, so just go through all the properties of `AVAsset` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/).